# How do I use IBM Filing Assistant on DOSBox?

Tags: dosbox

I would like to get specific step by step instructions on how to use an old word processor called IBM Filing Assistant on DOSBox to be able to access old 1980s documents.

How to use DOSBox other than with games?

Comment: It looks like File Assistant doesn’t work in DOSBox...

Comment: Unless perhaps with a [patch](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=5295).

Comment: the short answer is "you don't".  DOSBox is not intended to be used for applications, especially ones where preservation of data might be important.  It is intended to run games and only games.  Your best option is to use VM software such as VirtualBox, install real DOS inside that VM, and then run Filing Assistant there.

Comment: Thank you, peter ferry, I will attempt this.  Slowly as I am new at the whole thing but want to try to see if I can succeed in opening some archaic 1980s word files.  In the meantime, learning the old ways things were done.  Great to know there is so much knowledgeable people out there.

Comment: @peterferrie - DOSBox is perfectly good for running *most* applications. VirtualBox + MS-DOS might also have different incompatibilities, as it's really intended for virtualizing 32/64-bit OSs. DOSBox is a good first try.

Comment: @scruss, we don't make DOSBox to run applications.  We make it to run games.  That's why I wouldn't suggest to someone that DOSBox is a good choice here.

Comment: Maybe you should tell your docs people that, as the [application](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Software) section of the DOSBox website contains no such warning. It sounds like this old IBM software is expecting to run on real IBM hardware, which no Virtualbox (or DOSBox) setup will ever support. DOSBox is a great piece of software, and is much less tedious to set up than a VirtualBox MS-DOS image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it doesn't work in DOSBox then take a look at PCEm. It's a PC emulator that lets you emulate specific machine configurations.

Try to set up an emulated machine that matches one of the computers that the program could be used with.

https://pcem-emulator.co.uk

Comment: How do you know PCEm will not have the same issues that DOSBox has emulating the software?

Comment: I will try with PCem.

Comment: Has someone tried with DOSBOX and did not work for IBM Filing Assist?

Comment: @JAL: From the thread linked by Stephen Kitt, it seems the problem with IBM Filing Assistant is caused by DOSBOX's emulation of a DOS filesystem. PCEM doesn't emulate the filesystem; it uses an original copy of DOS, so would be unlikely to have that particular incompatibility.

Comment: DUDE, now that is interesting software!